# Anytime offpeak tickets: purchase in advance without specifying a day?

Tags: uk, national-rail

I often travel Oxford to London offpeak, so it'd be convenient if I could pre-purchase a stack of anytime offpeak tickets, rather than having to queue when I get to the train station (they only have a few machines). Is there a way to purchase these in advance without specifying a specific day/time? (If I knew the exact time I'd purchase an Advance ticket, but I usually don't.) I can't find anything on nationalrail.co.uk or gwr.com, but I haven't asked yet at the ticket counter in the the station.

Comment: Why not just buy tickets from a mobile app when you need them?

Comment: @JonathanReez GWR state that "You can buy mobile Off-Peak and Anytime tickets on most of our routes in and around Exeter, Paignton and Exmouth." which would exclude the area been Oxford and London. Chilton do though accept them in their Maralybone to Oxford trains.

Comment: @Calchas I'm asking about off-peak anytime tickets, not advance tickets.

Comment: @JonathanReez I just tried the GWR mobile app. They don't seem to do eTickets, which means now I've got to collect my ticket. This is actually slower than buying a new one (since it requires entering the 8 digits booking reference using their clumsy touchscreen!) Am I missing something? Chiltern Railways app is pretty bad, but it offers eTickets for Oxford Parkway to London Marylebone... maybe I can get an eticket through Chiltern that'd be valid Oxford->Paddington?

Comment: For some routes, you can buy a 'carnet'. ie a bundle of 10 tickets. Usually a bit cheaper than buying them individually.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get a London to Oxford carnet ticket - this is a book of 10 anytime day return tickets for the price of 9 valid for three months. However, it's quite hard to find information about this and I don't know much more about it. The tickets show up on [BRFares](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=1072&dest=OXF&tkt=GWD) and they seem to be priced by GWR - this would indicate to me they're valid on both Chiltern and GWR but I don't know for sure. [Chiltern advertise them](https://www.chilternrailways.co.uk/carnet-terms-and-conditions) as being available for purchase through Marylebone ticket office, and GWR [mention their existence](https://www.gwr.com/plan-journey/tickets-railcards-and-season-tickets/season-tickets) but they seem to  be available only through their business portal.

I would ask Chiltern and/or GWR's customer services for more details. Maybe you can get what you want. Do report back with your own answer here once you've figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to buy an off-peak ticket without specifying the day of travel.  In particular there is no system of "validation" as there is in France for example.

As comments have discussed, you might find that a Mobile eTicket resolves your issue, though this is not universally true across the network.